# Bxslider ticker mode

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, bxslider

I found bxslider ticker image slider looks fantastic. But I'm unable to implement it into my project.

I have:

```
 <html>

    <body>
        <!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
        <script src="@Url.Content("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js")"></script>
        <!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js")"></script>
        <!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css")" rel="stylesheet" /> </body> </html>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            minSlides: 4,
            maxSlides: 4,
            slideWidth: 170,
            slideMargin: 10,
            ticker: true,
            speed: 6000
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image]
[image]
My pictures should become horizontal instead of vertical.

Please advice.

Comment: I have tested it works perfectly at aspx file but not at cshtml

Comment: Try loading: `<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.css' rel='stylesheet'>` and `<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js'></script>` instead of the bxSlider stylesheet and JS file you are loading now.